# Embedded kafka-spring-test not working with kafka-clients 2.8.1

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

According to compatibility matrix https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka kafka-spring-test v2.7.12 should work with kafka-clients 2.7.0 - 2.8.1 but I'm getting runtime exceptions during embedded kafka tests.
pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.17</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.17</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Exception during runtime:

```
KafkaMsgFlowEmbeddedTest  Time elapsed: 2.005 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.ApiKeys.enabledApis()Ljava/util/List;
```

When I change kafka-clients to 2.7.2 all works fine. The problem is with 2.8.1. We are switching production to 2.8.1 so I need to test with this version of kafka-clients.

Could anyone advice how should I fix it?